# How often do my Mac contacts sync with Gmail?

Tags: macos, data-synchronization, contacts, gmail

I set up my Contacts in OS X Mountain Lion to sync with Gmail. I just went to Gmail and made some contact changes. How can I determine when this will sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've synced your contacts via Address Book then, if you want a deterministic way of syncing in addition to the periodic sync, you can invoke a sync manually from the menu bar app.

[image: Screenshot]

OSX is a bit unpleasant in that it will only add this menu item if you set up iCloud, **however, you can add this menu to your menu bar without iCloud :)** To do so, you need to open a file called `Sync.menu` located in `System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras` on your install volume (usually `Macintosh HD`).

You should only need to open this file once and then the menu item will remain on your menu bar until you remove it and should persist through logins and reboots.

If you want a **quick terminal command** to do the above then fire up Terminal and enter the following:

```
open /System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/Sync.menu
```